# How to add Primary key using new column in database

Tags: sql-server, primary-key

i converted my database from access to sql server ... now i want to replicate it and database is giving primary key error....i wrote below code to add a new column in all database but i am not able to convert the 'autoid' column as primary key...please help to solve it.

```
USE Aidherpnew
GO

IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#TempSysTableNames') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE #TempSysTableNames
END;


DECLARE @ColumnName VARCHAR(250) = 'autoid' 
        ,@DataType VARCHAR(250) = 'INT'
        ,@DefaultValue VARCHAR(250) = '1'
        ,@SQL VARCHAR(8000)
        ,@MaxRowNum INT
        ,@I INT = 1;
        
SELECT '[' + DB_NAME() + '].[' + OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME([object_id],DB_ID()) + '].[' + name + ']' AS [name]
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [create_date]) AS RowNum
INTO #TempSysTableNames
FROM sys.tables
WHERE [type] = 'U';

SET @MaxRowNum = (SELECT MAX(RowNum)
                 FROM #TempSysTableNames);

WHILE (@I <= @MaxRowNum)
BEGIN

    SET @SQL = (SELECT 'ALTER TABLE ' + [name] + ' ADD ' + @ColumnName + ' ' + @DataType + ' NOT NULL DEFAULT ' + @DefaultValue + ';'
                FROM #TempSysTableNames
                WHERE RowNum = @I);



    PRINT(@SQL);
   EXECUTE(@SQL);

    SET @I += 1;

END;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wanted to make the new column a `PRIMARY KEY` all you have to do is specify that in your add column script, assuming your tables don't already have one defined. You can accomplish this like so:

```
USE Aidherpnew
GO

IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#TempSysTableNames') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE #TempSysTableNames
END;


DECLARE @ColumnName VARCHAR(250) = 'autoid' 
        ,@DataType VARCHAR(250) = 'INT'
        ,@Constraints VARCHAR(250) = 'PRIMARY KEY'
        ,@DefaultValue VARCHAR(250) = '1'
        ,@SQL VARCHAR(8000)
        ,@MaxRowNum INT
        ,@I INT = 1;
        
SELECT '[' + DB_NAME() + '].[' + OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME([object_id],DB_ID()) + '].[' + name + ']' AS [name]
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [create_date]) AS RowNum
INTO #TempSysTableNames
FROM sys.tables
WHERE [type] = 'U';

SET @MaxRowNum = (SELECT MAX(RowNum)
                 FROM #TempSysTableNames);

WHILE (@I <= @MaxRowNum)
BEGIN

    SET @SQL = (SELECT 'ALTER TABLE ' + [name] + ' ADD ' + @ColumnName + ' ' + @DataType + ' NOT NULL ' + @Constraints + ' DEFAULT ' + @DefaultValue + ';'
                FROM #TempSysTableNames
                WHERE RowNum = @I);



    PRINT(@SQL);
   EXECUTE(@SQL);

    SET @I += 1;

END;
```

Here's some further documentation on [creating primary keys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/create-primary-keys?view=sql-server-ver16).

Comment: How well do you think creating primary keys with a default value of 1 is going to go?

Comment: @ErikDarling Good question for OP.  Pretty well if the table is rather empty.

Comment: great helped thanks